# Android WebView - navigating back on URL redirection

Tags: android

I have a question on the Android webview.

Assume URL A redirects to URL B.

My android application when it tries to open URL A, webview automatically redirects to URL B.

If a URL is being redirected to some other url, I see both these urls are stored in webview history. Now my webview history consists of [, , URL A, URL B ]

On back key click from URL B webpage, webview will try to load URL A, which again redirects to URL B. We need to double click back key to go back beyond URL A

How do I solve this issue ? Struggling from the past 2 hours :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992478/dead-loop-in-android-webview-backkey-for-redirect-href-link This will help

Answer (score 11):

**I have a same problem too, and figured out how to solve it.** It's like yours. When I click the first link(www.new.a) it automatically redirects other link(mobile.new.a). Usually the links redirect two or three, and my solution have been worked on almost every redirect links. I hope this answer help you out with annyoing redirecting links.

I finally figured out that. You need a [**WebViewClient**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) with four APIs. There are shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), onPageStarted(), onPageFinished(), and doUpdateVisitedHistory() in the WebViewClient. All the APIs you need is API 1 so don't worry about.

It goes like this. You can use other function rather than onKeyUp().

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{
    ...
    private int mRedirectedCount=0;
    .... 

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.canGoBack()) {
            if(mRedirectedCount>0){
                while(mRedirectedCount>0){
                    this.goBack();
                    mRedirectedCount--;
                }
                mRedirectedCount=0; //clear
            }else{
                this.goBack();
            }
        return true;
    }

    private class MyWebViewClinet extends WebViewClient{
        boolean mIsPageFinished=true;
        ...    

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            .....
            if(mIsPageFinished){
                mRedirectedCount=0; //clear count
            }
            .....
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mIsPageFinished = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mIsPageFinished = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);

            if(!mIsPageFinished){
                mRedirectedCount++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I use OnBackPressed() instead of onKeyUp and it doesn't work

Comment: Using "do while" should be better.

Answer (score 7):

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
}

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

If overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, then return false.
May not be correct way but it works for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Returning true at shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is what triggers the issue in the first place, since the API sees that as an explicit URL load, which is added to the back stack, not treated as a common redirect (which is not added to the back stack).

Comment: I agree that this should be the accepted answer.  Returning `false` produces the expected results.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Answer (score 0):

**i have the problem too**, now already solved the problem.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33148779/1528524)

**If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url. **

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN 2022**

(Ignore some my codes, for example "intent.extras" or "with(webView.settings)" - if you don't need these settings of webView and yes I am not using viewBinding!!!)

Tried all my best to solve this problem + also fixed: when you clicking some toolbars in webpage which is something like show something without opening a new url, it was adding('cuz onTouch see below) current url again to our arrayList and when you were clicking "back" it was refreshing -> current url to current url.
Best solution is here:

```
class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnTouchListener {
    private lateinit var url: String
    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private var mLastUrl: String? = null
    private val previous: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web)
        url = intent.extras!!.getString("url").toString()

        webView = findViewById(R.id.appWebView)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressBar)
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
        webView.webViewClient = (object : WebViewClient(){
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                Log.i("DebugDebug", "OnPageFinished " + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                mLastUrl = url
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })
        webView.setOnTouchListener(this)

        with(webView.settings) {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
            databaseEnabled = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            setSupportZoom(true)
            defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
        }
        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, mE: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val hr = (v as WebView).hitTestResult
        if(hr != null && mLastUrl != null){
            if (previous.isEmpty() || previous[previous.size - 1] != mLastUrl) previous.add(mLastUrl!!)
        }
        Log.i("DebugDebug", "getExtra = " + hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type = " + hr.getType())
        return false
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        Log.i("DebugDebug", "onBackPressed loaded and removed" + previous.toString());
        if (previous.size > 0 && webView.url != previous[previous.size - 1]){
            webView.loadUrl(previous[previous.size - 1])
            previous.removeAt(previous.size - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to overload the OnBackPressed() to overide the default hard key back action. there u can finish the current activity or control how you want.

Comment: Did not get you. How can I get to know if the URL is a redirected URL or a regular URL ? Also, is it possible to delete a particualr URL from the webview history ?