# Android WebView: EditText that displays URL doesn't refresh after goBack or goForward

Tags: android, webview

So I have a WebView, and there is an EditText which a user can type in a URL then press the Go button to navigate to that URL. There are also a back button and forward button which seem to work fine (just calling goBack() and goForward() ).

Now, the problem is refreshing the EditText to display the correct URL anytime the back or forward buttons are pressed. Sometimes it seems to work fine, but more often it will lag behind the click by 1 webpage. What I mean by this is that if I am on a webpage (call this WP2) and click back, the webpage shown will go back to the previous one (WP1) correctly, but the URL will initially stay the same in the editText (WP2). If I click back again, the webpage will go back once again fine (WP0), but now the editText shows the URL for the previously displayed webpage (WP1).

I hope my problem is clear enough, and if anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

EDIT: I should probably post some code, so here it is:

My goBack button OnClick:

```
leftWebViewBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WebView webView = webViewFrag.web; //this is getting the webview from its fragment.
                webView.goBack();
                urlEditText.setText(webView.getUrl());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation for [getUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()) it says

> Gets the URL for the current page. This is not always the same as the URL passed to WebViewClient.onPageStarted because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed.

Your best bet is to override `WebViewClient#onPageStarted()` and use `setWebViewClient(...)`. It's also possible you'll get into some redirect loop like mentioned here ([WebView back history without redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784685/webview-back-history-without-redirects)) so you might want to consider this (unless you know you won't encounter them).

The code might look like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    ....

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        urlEditText.setText(url);
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: This seems like it is probably true. I will play around with fixing the code and if I can get it to work will mark as correct (Can't up vote cuz my account score is too low sorry). Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Awesome worked perfectly! I think the first time I tried it I put it under setWebChromeClient instead and it wasn't working then. But now perfect! :D Thanks very much for your help!