# Android webview go back in a single page app with redirect

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, webview

In my android app I am using a webview to navigate a single page app, built in angularJs.

The different views in the web app are navigated to using relative URLs e.g. #/login.

The methods goBack() and canGoBack() work fine, until they hit a page that has a redirect. E.G. the user is on page 2, goBack() takes the user to page 1, which redirects to page 2.

The previous solutions to this problem, e.g. [WebView back history without redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784685/webview-back-history-without-redirects), use the method:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading() {
    //check if a redirect is happening here and if so, go back again
}
```

However this is of no use to me, as because the urls are all relative, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called (another reason it may not be called is that the links just trigger javascript rather than make GET requests to new URLs).

I figured one way to fix this problem could be:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if(isGoingBack()) {
        if(isRedirect()) {
            goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to implement those methods! Another thing to note is that

```
getOriginalUrl()
```

Always returns the same initial url (no matter how much the user navigates around the webpage). However,

```
getCurrentUrl()
```

does return the correct url.

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated!