# Android hardware back button doesn't work after HTTP redirect

Tags: php, android, cordova, button, back

I have an app that have a login page, the form action is a php file on the server and if the login is successful, it redirects to the member page in the server.

the member page is actually one page inside the items of tab, when I try to browse through the pages in the tab, clicking back button doesn't work.

I tried without HTTP redirect, the hardware back button works.
When I debug it in chrome, the back button works.

P.S. I am using Ionic and use $state to go through pages.

Can anyone please advise how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: This is probably your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16795181/513413

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. However, I am using HTML/javascript to write my app, how can I override the back button as suggested in the post ?

Comment: Are you using Native Android or Phonegap/Xamarin? The suggested way is based on Webview which is Native Android. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with nonnative stuff :(

Comment: I am using Cordova and also using ionic as my framework, thanks for trying to help :)!

Comment: You are welcome. Please add `Cordova` as tag to tag list too. It helps your question founded easily by their QA team (if they have such a team).