# Android WebView canGoBack always return true in a page with redirect

Tags: android, redirect, webview

In my app I use a `webView` to navigate a web page.

```
if (webView.canGoBack()) {
    webView.goBack();
}
```

The methods `goBack()` and `canGoBack()` work fine, until they hit a page that has a redirect.

E.G.the `webView` loads page0, the redirect to page1, when the user press back, the webView loads page0, which redirects to page1 again. This means the user cannot go back anymore.

How to solve this question. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011207/android-webview-navigating-back-on-url-redirection)? It works for my redirect problem

Comment: @saki_M thanks, the second answer works.